# Python Datetime issue with Jenkins API

Tags: python, django, jenkins

I have a Django application that integrates with the Jenkins API (jenkinsapi).  I am calling the get_timestamp() method on the Build object.  In Interactive mode, it returns a date string like "2013-05-07 09:29:46"; however, from within Django, it returns a long which I assumed was a Unix datetimestamp, but it is a date so far in the future that I get ValueError: year is out of range.  The value it is returning is 1368805100576.

```
>>> b = api.get_jobs()
>>> for job in b:
...     last_build = job[1].get_last_build_or_none()
...     print last_build.id(), last_build.get_timestamp() 
...
3 2013-05-07 09:29:46
2 2013-05-07 09:28:52
```

And from non-interactive mode:

```
print current_build.get_timestamp()
friendly_timestamp =       datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(current_build.get_timestamp())).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
ValueError: year is out of range
```

Any idea why these would be different and what is that long that get_timestamp is returning?

Comment: what does `print current_build.get_timestamp()` give you ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like that is in milliseconds,

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1368805100576/1000)
datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 17, 8, 38, 20)
```

Comment: I also discovered there was a bug in the version of jenkinsapi I had.